# Deploying a Rails API on either Heroku/AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, heroku, puma, rails-api

I'm trying to pair a mobile client with a REST API so that I get JSON data which I can display in the app. I'm following Apis on Rails by Abraham Kuri Vargas. In the API I have created a subdomain as well as some versioning, so the controller files are in app/controllers/api/v1. The API returns desired JSON data when I run it locally. The problem I'm facing is whenever I deploy the API onto Heroku/AWS it will show "Application not found". Is it that the remote server isn't finding its way into app/controllers/api/v1? Is there any fix for a problem like this because even in the book the author has written "Due to the structure of the application we are not going to deploy the app to any server". I'm really stuck on this problem for a long time and would love any suggestions!

**app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb**

```
    class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
     respond_to :json

     def show
      respond_with User.find(params[:id])
     end

     def create
     user = User.new(user_params)
      if user.save
       render json: user, status: 201, location: [ :api,user ]
      else
       render json: { errors: user.errors }, status: 422
      end
     end

     def update
     user = User.find(params[:id])
      if user.update(user_params)
       render json: user, status: 200, location: [ :api,user ]
      else
       render json: { errors: user.errors }, status: 422
      end
     end

     def destroy
      user = User.find(params[:id])
      user.destroy
      head 204
     end

     private
      def user_params
       params.require(:user).permit(:email,:password,:password_confirmation)
      end
    end
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
    require 'api_constraints'

    Rails.application.routes.draw do

      devise_for :users
      namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: '/'  do
        scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
          #resources 
          resources :users, :only => [:show, :create, :update, :destroy]
        end 
      end
    end
```

**Output, when I run localhosts://3000/users/1 locally**

{"id":1,"email":"example@marketplace.com","created_at":"2016-06-09T05:36:06.606Z","updated_at":"2016-06-09T05:36:06.606Z"}

**Heroku server logs when I run petoye.herokuapp.com/users/1**

Started GET "/users/1" for 120.60.22.244 at 2016-06-12 06:43:36 +0000
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/1"):
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'

vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in`call_app'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'

vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in`tagged'   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'

vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in`call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'

2016-06-12T06:43:36.946702+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in`call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/server.rb:569:in `handle_request'

vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:114:in`block in spawn_thread'

Comment: can you post the log from the server from your request?

Comment: Updated the post with server logs. Will you take a look? Thanks. One thing I noticed is that even when I run the same thing locally with puma I get the same exact error. However when I use WEBrick there's no problem.

Comment: yep, it looks like you're having trouble getting your puma server running

Comment: I don't think the puma server is meant for hosting a Rails API. It works fine when working with any rails application.

Comment: should be fine. this may help https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Steps on how to configure Heroku for a Rails API**

1. First you need to buy a domain using any registrar, say you buy www.example.com, so you can use a subdomain like api.example.com. Once that's done you need to tell heroku to listen to requests at api.example.com. This can be done easily by typing this on your cmd

   ```
   heroku domains:add api.example.com
   ```
2. After using the domains:add command you must point your DNS provider at the domain’s DNS Target supplied by Heroku. This is done by creating a CNAME entry to something like example.herokuapp.com (type heroku info to get the name of your app). The above process is made simple if you use a service like DNSimple (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rr6Jy9i0Cws). Basically you add a CNAME record of api.example.com which points to example.herokuapp.com
3. One important thing everyone forgets once they deploy to heroku is to run the heroku run rake db:migrate command.

Once all this is done you would be able to access the api using api.example.com/any_endpoints

Additional resources: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains
https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/alias-record/

Answer (score 3):

The problem with heroku is that if you don't pay for a domain, and just use the base service, it will assign a subdomain for your app. So all I needed to do was to redirect heroku to a custom url such as api.any_domain.com.

An easier alternative would be to override the constraints for the api on the routes.rb file:

```
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, path: '/api'  do
```

You will now be able to see the API under http://herokuapp.com/api/any_endpoint